# Is there a way to determine if a logged in user has been to the current page?

Tags: user

My goal is to highlight a help area the first time a logged in user goes to a specific page.  The page has lots of complicated functions and it is a constant source of questions.  Ideally this would give the users a readily available source of answers for their questions.

I do not want this to happen every time they log in.  Pushing help at users when they don't need it just tends to irritate people.

My compromise is to see if a user have been on the page before and give them additional information if they have not been to that location.

Does anyone know how I would do this?  I am looking for either PHP, Javascript or a plugin that would help me accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use a modal popup, there are several extensions that will display only the first time someone visits the page in question (this is determined by setting a cookie). Add your instructions in your popup, and maybe a link on your page to display the popup again in case the user wants to see the information again.

#### NoNumber Modals

NoNumber has a nice popup extension called [Modals](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modals), and it has an option to display popup only once (I think you need the pro version for this):

```
{modal html=This modal will only show once|openOnce=1}{/modal}
```

Check out the [demo here](http://demo.nonumber.nl/index.php/12-modals).

#### Joomla Content Editor

The Joomla Content Editor also has a function to display a popup only once. Read more here: https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/tutorials/jcemediabox/item/create-a-media-popup

```
<a href="/instructions.html" class="jcepopup autopopup-single" type="text/html" id="autopopup"></a>
```

#### Other extensions

You can find other extensions at the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes).

Comment: Thank you johanpw.  That was exactly what I was looking for and I also happen to be a Pro subscriber at NoNumber, so that solution works and is available.

Comment: It really amazes me how the Joomla Stackexchange people are so much more helpful that what I normally find at the Joomla forums. Thankfully this exists now.